# How to you store videos/clips in xampp?

Tags: php, apache, video, xampp

I recently just installed **xampp on windows**. I'd like to know how I can store video/clips in a database. I have the video clip stored in the htdocs folder and where it says "value" in the xampp database, I place the file directory followed by the file name (`C:\xampp\htdocs\firstsite\check_php\helgo.mp4` , however when I refresh and display my work in preview mode, the video doesnt appear and only a text string appears. The type is set to VARCHAR(255).

example below......

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\firstsite\check_php\helgo.mp4
```

**how do I get my webpage to correctly display the video?**

Yes my testing server is correct and functional. I also use dreamweaver.

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\firstsite\check_php\admin\Untitled-2.php on line 9

Comment: You can't store videos or anything in your xampp. Because it is just the webserver. You can store the video files in your system and store the path in your database (mysql). Learn more about PHP - MYSQL http://www.w3schools.com/Php/php_mysql_intro.asp

Comment: thats what Ive tried to do. I have the video in my xampp folder. In my database where it says value I copy and paste the directory and file name of where my file is located and the name and file type or the video.

Comment: You should follow the correct structure for doing that. If your video's path is htdocs/project/media/a.flv, the path should be stored as media/a.flv

Comment: It doesnt work... I will try and clarify. I have the video in the following file path: C:\xampp\htdocs\firstsite\helgo.mp4. Inside xampp database, the record has the following properties type=VARCHAR(255) function= I leave empty and value= C:\xampp\htdocs\firstsite\helgo.mp4. Am I doing something wrong.

Comment: No, You should store the value as \helgo.mp4

Comment: What should I store the value as??

Comment: it still doesnt work. Once I preview it in my browser - a text string appears -\helgo.mp4 instead of the actual video. I know it works if I embed videos from youtube that works fine, but when I try to get the server to display a video form my computer it just doesnt work. I apologize if Im not using the correct terminology.

Comment: I will give you correct procedure to do it in few min.

Comment: ok thank you I will wait for your response.

Comment: I have answered, Kindly check it out.

Comment: thanks for your help but it still did not work. I will seek further help from this website. Thanks though.

Comment: Ok, if you are done. Kindly tell me. So that i can improve myself. (You shall also check my answer which is prepared specially for you)

Comment: Tell me how do you paste screenshots in the comment section?

Comment: If you earn enough reputation. You can able to paste screenshots

Comment: the video is 11mb is that a problem?

Comment: It might be a problem. You just try with smaller video.

Comment: <video controls>
    <source src="helgo.mp4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>

Comment: I added that in the value bar and it worked. But when I try your method it doesnt.

Comment: To follow my method. you should create a table, connection file etc., Have you created it ?

Answer (score 0):

Use some plugin for video clips to show (like [JW player](http://www.jwplayer.com/about-jwplayer/)), and pass to that plugin video path value from database. Or just add that entry from database to link as href attribute.

Answer (score 0):

First, store video path information in your database. then use any player to load this video

Answer (score 0):

First Store a Video in your Folder as shown below :

[image: First Image]
Then Create a Table with the Following Query :

```
CREATE TABLE `video` (
`id` int(4) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`path` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

And then insert a data of your video path as shown below :

[image]

Here is the PHP Code to Play the Video :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<?php
require ('config.php');
$a=mysql_query('select path from video where id=1;');
$b=mysql_fetch_array($a);

?>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="<?php echo $b['path']?>">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>

<video src="a.mov" width=”640” height=”360”></video>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Output :

[image]